# Eclipse Mountain Lion scrollbar expanding

Tags: eclipse, osx-mountain-lion

I'm having an issue with mountain lion, which is decreasing my productivity a LOT.

When using cmd+mouse click (I assume ctrl+mouse click) on a method/class/whatever I get the Open declaration/implementation etc popup. The problem is that the scrollbar lies over the bottom most item and since it's expanding on mouse over there's no way to select that item.

Is there any workaround for this? Or a way to make the popup bigger? Or select the using the keyboard?

Comment: Is the bottom most item always the same?  Maybe you can assign a shortcut to it and use a key combo instead of a mouse shortcut?

Comment: no... can be an xml resource/java class, method, interface etc :(

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Thanks to a friend I found a solution! If you change scrollbar visibility to always (System Preferences - General) they aren't appearing at all in the popups!

Comment: fyi: in the end I actually switched to IntelliJ because the always visible scrollbars annoyed me - it's so much better!

Answer (score 4):

While switching to "Show scroll bars: Always" is one alternative, I think it would be better to get this resolved in Eclipse, thus I filed a bug:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=387095

Comment: FYI this bug is fixed and available in Juno SR1 which is available since a couple of weeks: http://eclipse.org/downloads/

Answer (score 2):

Check **[this](http://youtu.be/qV7EmzozI0o)** screencast I made to show the relation between the Mountain Lion Preferences and how it effects Eclipse.

For me it's only the `When Scrolling` option that creates a problem. With either of the remaining settings, things are peachy :

[image]